# new to flutter. I'm want to go to a webapi based on url passed not hard code path

Tags: flutter

I'm working with web API's and need to pass in a api url that I retrieved to fetch some data then display the data. I am able to create a listview from a api url that's hard coded, but don't know how to send in a parameter to display info based on that selected url. How do send in the url fetch the data and display it

----------api_data_details.dart file---------

```
    class PokemonRepository {
   //want to pass in a url

  final String url ;

  PokemonRepository({this.url});



  final JsonDecoder _decoder = new JsonDecoder();

  Future<Pokemon> fetch() async{
    final detailsresponse = await http.get(url);
    final jsonBody = detailsresponse.body;
    final statusCode = detailsresponse.statusCode;

    if(statusCode < 200 || statusCode >= 300 || jsonBody == null) {
      throw new FetchDataException("Error while getting pokemon details [StatusCode:$statusCode, Error:${detailsresponse.reasonPhrase}]");
    }

    final pokemonContainer = _decoder.convert(jsonBody);
    final  pokemonDetails = pokemonContainer['results'];

    return pokemonDetails.map( (pokemondetails) => 
  Pokemon.fromMap(pokemondetails)) ;

  }
```

--------------api_data.dart file--------------

```
  class Pokemon{
    final int id;
    final String name;
    final int height;
    final List<Moves> moves;
    final String imageUrl;
    final int weight;


  const Pokemon({this.id,this.name,this.height, this.weight,this.imageUrl,this.moves});
  Pokemon.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map):
              id = map['id'],
              name = map['name'],
              height = map['height'],
              imageUrl = map['sprites']['front-default'],
              weight = map['weight'],
              moves = <Moves>[
                    new Moves(name: map['name'])
              ];

}
class Moves {
 final String name;

  const Moves({this.name});
}
abstract class PokemonDetailRepository{

  Future<Pokemon> fetch();
 }
```

---------------pokemon_view.dart file----------------

```
 class _PokemonListItem extends ListTile {
_PokemonListItem(PokemonList pokemonlist):
 super(

      title : Text(pokemonlist.name),

      subtitle: InkWell(
         child: Text(pokemonlist.url, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 8.0),),
        onTap: (){

          //want to click on url and pass it to the PokemonRepository class to retrieve the new data and then open a new page with the details from the new request
            // Navigator.push(
            //     context,
            //     MaterialPageRoute(
            //       builder: (context) => PokemonDetailPage( pokemonlist.url,),
        }
     )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just pass the url in to the `fetch` function as a parameter? 
So the signature for `fetch` becomes:

```
Future<Pokemon> fetch(String url) {
// do stuff
}
```

If you want to pass a default value, the syntax is a little different:

```
Future<Pokemon> fetch({String url = "http://default"}) {
// do stuff
}
```

And then the caller can choose to pass a url or not.

Remember that Flutter is written in Dart, so ultimately you're just writing dart code. For language-related questions (like how to pass parameters to functions) the [language tour](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour) is an excellent resource.